# launchctl root access and logged in user names?

Tags: cocoa, remote-desktop, client-server

I'm writing an app to do remote management; rather, it's already done. My problem is I need it to start at launch like ARDAgent, and the issue with this is when I send a message or copy a file, ARD requires me to be logged in. For my app, I would rather it not, so how would I let my app run as root, but still know who the logged in user is (or how to know if there is none).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone asking, there is no way, as launchctl will only load as the logged in user, not root, for security reasons. There is a Carbon function to find the current console user from a  daemon, however.